# Sorting an array based on times

Tags: javascript, sorting, momentjs

I have an array of objects containing time stamps and I am attempting to sort them in ascending order. Ive tried converting them to 24 hour time using moment when sorting also comparing the time stamps themselves but for some reason I am still getting my times in a random order. Is there something Im missing?

data when already converted 12 hour time

```
[{start: '9:04 AM', end: '9:34 AM'}, {start: '3:04 AM', end: '3:34 AM'}...]
```

```
const sortedAppointments = appointments.sort(
    (a, b) => moment(a.start).format("H:mm") - moment(b.start).format("H:mm"),
  );
```

note: I am mapping over the array in the UI after it is sorted. But the output from this sort function is still out of order "/

Answer (score 3):

Read the times into moment with the correct format, then compare the UNIX timestamps.

```js
const sortedAppointments = appointments.sort(
    (a, b) => moment(a.start, "h:mm a").unix() - moment(b.start, "h:mm a").unix()
);
```

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, here's a version without the 200+kb download of moment.js

```js
let appointments = [{
  start: '9:04 AM',
  end: '9:34 AM'
}, {
  start: '9:04 PM',
  end: '10:34 PM'
}, {
  start: '3:04 AM',
  end: '3:34 AM'
}]
const conv = time => {
  let mer = time.split(" ")[1].toLowerCase(),
    tm = time.split(" ")[0].split(":");
  if (mer === "pm") tm[0] = +tm[0] + 12;
  return +tm.join('');
}
const sortedAppointments = appointments.sort(
  (a, b) => conv(a.start) - conv(b.start)
);

console.log(sortedAppointments)
```

Answer (score -2):

This is the solution that worked best for me with time in UTC :

```
const sortedAppointments = appointments.sort(
    (a, b) => moment(a.start).format("x") - moment(b.start).format("x"),
  );
```

Comment: This does not work as discussed in a deleted post. `moment(a.start).format("x")` gives "invalid date". The post you copied this from was deleted for this reason.

Comment: But it returned valid dates for me and fixed my issue? What about it is invalid?

Comment: using your example data, moment returns "Invalid date" and throws a deprecated warning. https://i.imgur.com/DUhnVcU.png

Comment: Ah I see, I moved the sorting up in the code and sorted before the time was converted from UTC. Using this .format("x") on utc didnt give me any errors. I will clarify.

Comment: still .format("x") gives a string and implicit type conversions with string subtraction is both bad practice and has poor performance.